# JSON Serialize - Modify Resulting Property Name

Tags: json, linux, serialization, vala

I am trying to use this library to serialize a class I wrote. [Valadoc : gobject_to_data](https://valadoc.org/json-glib-1.0/Json.gobject_to_data.html).

Suppose I have a class written like this:

```
public class MyObject : Object {
    public string property_name { get; set; }

    public MyObject (string str) {
        this.property_name = property_name;
    }
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject ("my string");

    string data = Json.gobject_to_data (obj, null);
    print (data);
    print ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output I see is:

```
{
  "property-name" : "my string"
}
```

What I want to do is modify the property name to instead be in "Snake case":

```
{
  "property_name" : "my string"
}
```

How can I do that?

I have tried implementing `serialize_property` from the `Serializable` interface like this:

```
public class MyObject : Object : Json.Serializable {
     public string property_name { get; set; }

     public MyObject (string str) {
    this.property_name = property_name;
     }

     public Json.Node serialize_property(string property_name, Value value, ParamSpec pspec) {
        string property_name_camel_case = property_name.replace("-", "_");

        Json.Node value_node = new Json.Node(Json.NodeType.VALUE);
        value_node.set_value(value);

        Json.Object final_object = new Json.Object();
        final_object.set_member(property_name_camel_case, value_node);

        return value_node;
    }
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject ("my string");

    string data = Json.gobject_to_data (obj, null);
    print (data);
    print ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

However, I still receive this output:

```
{
  "property-name" : "my string"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer in case anyone else is looking for this**

Unfortunately, JSON serialization does not support non-canonical names [see here](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.ParamSpec.html). When you are implementing `Json.Serializable.list_properties`, you still cannot create any kind of `ParamSpec` with a non-canonical name.

Because of this, I had to resort to building a `Json.Object` and manually setting each of the key-value pairs myself like this:

```
    public string to_json() {
        // None of these names are canonical, so we have to write them manually
        Json.Object main_object = new Json.Object();
        main_object.set_string_member("@type", "setTdlibParameters");
        main_object.set_string_member("database_directory", database_directory);
        main_object.set_boolean_member("enable_storage_optimizer", enable_storage_optimizer);

        Json.Node wrapper = new Json.Node(Json.NodeType.OBJECT);
        wrapper.set_object(main_object);

        Json.Generator generator = new Json.Generator();
        generator.set_root(wrapper);

        return generator.to_data(null);
    }
```